# Cannot find TextView in PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, textview, preferenceactivity

In my PreferenceActivity I have some Preferences.
One I inflate from layout:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.settings);
   ...
}

protected void onResume() {     
    super.onResume();
    Preference registrationStatus = (Preference) findPreference("registrationStatusPref");
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(somestring){
       registrationStatus.setLayoutResource(R.layout.push_reg_status);
       TextView push_reg_status_txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pushRegTxtPref);
    }
    ....
}
```

`push_reg_status_txt` is a TextView from `push_reg_status` layout, and `push_reg_status_txt`  is always null.

**push_reg_status** layout:

```
....
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/pushRegTxtPref"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:text="Registration Succesful"
        android:textColor="#99ff33"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
.....
```

Why?

Answer (score 3):

`Preference.setLayoutResource()` only updates the internal reference that preference has to a layout ID, it does not actually update the layout to redisplay.  Therefore the TextView you are looking for with `findViewById()` is not inflated for your use.  The only place Preferences inflate their layouts is when created.

You'll either need to have that custom layout set at the start (before `addPreferencesFromResource()` inflates everything), or adjust the title/summary properties of the existing preference instead to set your "Registration Successful" string.  Also, if you are using a custom preference layout, make sure you're following the rules set forth in the [SDK Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setLayoutResource%28int%29).

Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you calls findViewById of your Activity instead of calling same method of registrationStatus object.

Comment: registrationStatus is Preference.
And push_reg_status_txt is TextView from layout which inflate this Preference.
How can I call findViewById for Preference??