# Getting reference to Button in layout created by PreferenceActivity

Tags: java, android

I've got a ImageView in a SharedPreferences layout file I'm trying to get a reference to so I can create an listener for in my PrefsActivity class. So far I haven't had any luck getting a reference using findViewById everything comes back as null.

The setup looks like:

**PrefsActivity.class**

```
public class PrefsActivity extends UnifiedSherlockPreferenceActivity {

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Set header resource MUST BE CALLED BEFORE super.onCreate 
        setHeaderRes(R.xml.pref_headers);
        // Set desired preference file and mode (optional)
        setSharedPreferencesName("my_prefs");
        setSharedPreferencesMode(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ACRA.init(getApplication());

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.new);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

**pref_headers.xml**

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:unified="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<header
    unified:fragment="com.my.app.PrefsActivity$GeneralPreferenceFragment"
    unified:title="@string/pref_header_general"
    unified:preferenceRes="@xml/pref_general" />
```

**pref_general.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<PreferenceCategory
android:title="Category Title"
android:layout="@layout/settings_message"

<EditTextPreference
    android:capitalize="words"
    android:defaultValue=""
    android:inputType="textCapWords"
    android:key="first_name"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:title="@string/first_name" />
```

**settings_message.xml**

This contains the button btnTutorial i'm trying to get a reference to

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSettingsMessage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20px"
    android:text="@string/settings_text" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnTutorial"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20px"
    android:text="@string/settings_button_text" />
```

Comment: Perhaps you're getting null because of this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5704613/858626

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the following method in your `onCreate()`...

```
setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
```

...so null values are returned. Try to implement these changes, then let us know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your input Karan. There isn't a setContentView() because I assume the UnifiedSherlockPreferenceActivity creates the view on the fly using R.xml.pref_headers. Although I have noticed I've missed one of the xml files out which I'll now update

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can access your imageView from the method 'onPreferenceTreeClick' like :

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen,
        Preference preference) {
    super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preferenceScreen, preference);
    if (preference != null && preference.getKey().equals("imageViewKey")) {
        // do something here
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

In your settings_message.xml set atribute for button

android:onClick="onLogoutClick"

In activity PrefsActivity define method public void onLogoutClick(View v) { }

You are ready to go! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Preference myPreference = findPreference(key);
```

where key is the key in your XML, e.g., "first_name".